# Setting frame for subview's subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame

I have view controller defined by xib.

In this view controller I add subclassed UIView. On this subclassed UIView I want to add another uiview.

I have variable nextRound that is of my custom view data type. I init it like:

```
    NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FDCOStaticNextRound" owner:self options:nil];
    nextRound = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
    nextRound.frame =  CGRectZero;
    nextRound.alpha = 0.8;
    [self addSubview:nextRound];
```

After putting breakpoints, nextRound's frame is indeed 0,0,0,0 however, it is added with it's xib's frame (0,0,320,91).

I try to animate it when reaching next rounds (so it is presented for couple of seconds, and then dismissed with rollup/down animation). However even changing frame there seems to do nothing. Breakpoint-wise, frame changes, but actual view on screen doesn't do anything.

Autolayout is turned off, size inspector - autosizing is set only to top left. I've got similar feature right in view controller, and there, it works flawlessly, so I guess it has to do something with it being added to another custom view.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Well, I add subview, change it's frame to 0,0,0,0 but after I add it with [self addSubView:nextRound] it is added with it's original frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. In my xib(attribute inspector), I didn't have option clip subviews enabled :-/